# Launcher service doesn't auto start on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: install4j

For Linux installer, we have added a custom launcher for auto start of service (see pic below).
We are using install4j v5.1.6. It creates a link in /etc/init.d/myService.sh which points to the /bin/myService.sh .

It works properly in Ubuntu 13. On system restart, service auto starts properly.

On Ubuntu 14 this doesn't work. Service starts first time after installation. But on system restart, service doesn't auto start.

On further investigation, running these commands on Ubuntu 14 enabled auto start.

```
   after installation
   cd /etc/init.d
   sudo update-rc.d myService.sh defaults
```

Under installer,  install a service, auto start is set to true. 
Is this a limitation of install4j that it doesn't register with update-rc.d ?
Do we know on which Linux systems copying to /etc/init.d/ is sufficient ?

Our script is similar to : www.shayanderson.com/linux/add-startup-script-or-service-with-linux-on-bootup.htm  . What we don't have is update-rc.d and chkconfig. And install4j does the task of copying it to /etc/init.d/

Thanks !

http://s27.postimg.org/o5bih55kz/Launcher_Configuration.png
http://s3.postimg.org/icitxy96b/Launcher_Setup.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 5.1.x, install4j does not integrate services into runlevels, it only creates the symlink to the start script in /etc/init.d.

Integrating it into runlevels has to be done manually, such as by calling update-rc.d or whatever other tool the particular distribution provides.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do we know on which Linux systems copying to /etc/init.d/ is sufficient ? This will save me investigation effort. Am thinking of detecting the Linux OS type and running a shell script that can run update-rc.d command.

Comment: I don't think update-rc.d is available in every Linux distribution, it depends on the init system. I did not know that for some distributions the presence of the start script in /etc/init.d would cause it to be executed during the startup sequence.